costumize the chapter title in the class "book"
I would like to costumize the chapter title in the class "book" so that I have two . the second one should be shown on the right side like in the Example out of MCWord

Do you also want to change he TOC and headers?  Will the title always fit in one line?  If not, you should use a tabular.  Note: you will probably also want to change \chapter* which is used for things like the TOC.

The best for me would be if only the left side of the titles would be shown in the TOC. The title should definitely fit only in one line. There wouldn't be any check necessary. I would like to have a command like \chapter for it.

Look at the result of compiling \documentclass[english]{book}\begin{document}\chapter{Title of the first chapter}\end{document}: When with book class you say \chapter{Title of first chapter} , then you get two lines. The first line holds the word "Chapter" and the number of the chapter. The second line holds the title of the chapter, i.e.,"Title of the first chapter". Where do you wish your second title (Jon/Sara) to appear? In the first line?In the second line? Also with book class each chapter begins on a new (recto) page which doesn't seem to be the case with the chapters in your image.

Chapter titles in the documentclass book are so-called moving arguments: They go into the main text, they go into the table of contents, they go into page headers. When pdfTeX/hyperref/nameref is used they also go into \nameref-references and into pdf-bookmarks.
For answering the question properly, specification is needed what is wanted in each of these situations.
Unfortunately LaTeX does not bring along something like "situation management" so that you could query a flag for finding out what LaTeX currently is doing.
But for the book class you can probably write a command \ForkEntriesByPurpose (which can be considered a rather crude hack where I cannot tell you if it will still work out when things in the book class get changed!) which can be used inside the optional argument of sectioning commands like \chapter or section as follows:
⟨sectioning command⟩[%
                      \ForkEntriesByPurpose
                      {⟨Entry with this item of sectioning for the page headers⟩}%
                      {⟨Entry with this item of sectioning for the table of contents or the list of figures/tables⟩}%
                      {⟨Entry with this item of sectioning for nameref reference⟩}%
                      {⟨Entry with this item of sectioning for the bookmarks⟩}%
                    ]%
                    {%
                      ⟨Entry with this item of sectioning for heading or caption in the main text⟩%
                    }%
I don't know whether \ForkEntriesByPurpose still works out when you load packages like minitoc or titlesec or titletoc or bookmark !
Minimal example:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[unicode=false]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ForkEntriesByPurpose{%
  \ifx\protect\@unexpandable@protect
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\protect\@ForkEntriesByPurpose
   \protect\@ForkEntriesByPurpose
   \protect\@ForkEntriesByPurpose
  }%
  {\expandafter\texorpdfstring\@gobbletwo}%
}
\@ifdefinable\@ForkEntriesByPurpose{%
  \def\@ForkEntriesByPurpose#1#{%
    \ifx#1\expandafter\@secondoffour\else\expandafter\@firstoffour\fi
  }%
}
\newcommand\@firstoffour[4]{#1}
\newcommand\@secondoffour[4]{#2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter[\ForkEntriesByPurpose{Entry with this chapter for the page headers}%
                              {Entry with this chapter for the  table of contents}%
                              {Entry with this chapter for nameref references}%
                              {Entry with this chapter for the bookmarks}%
        ]{Entry with this chapter for the heading in the main text}
\label{this chapter}
nameref reference: \nameref{this chapter}
\newpage 
text \newpage text
\section[\ForkEntriesByPurpose{Entry with this section for the page headers}%
                              {Entry with this section for the table of contents}%
                              {Entry with this section for nameref references}%
                              {Entry with this section for the bookmarks%
                               \texorpdfstring{---}{\ifpdfstringunicode{\9040\024}{\204}}%
                               it has an emdash so you can see handling of special symbols %
                               within bookmarks%
                              }%
        ]{Entry with this section for the heading in the main text}
\label{this section}
nameref reference: \nameref{this section}
\newpage
text \newpage
\begin{figure}
\fbox{This is a figure}
\caption[\ForkEntriesByPurpose{Entry with this caption for the the page headers; somewhat obsolete with figures}%
                              {Entry with this caption for the list of figures}%
                              {Entry with this caption for nameref references}%
                              {Entry with this caption for the bookmarks; somewhat obsolete with figures}%
        ]{Entry with this caption for the main text}%
\label{this caption}%
\end{figure}
nameref reference: \nameref{this caption}
\newpage
text
\newpage

\end{document}

    %------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Remark: Deliver emdash in pdfstring/bookmark:
    %..............................................................................
    % pdfstrings can either be encoded in PDFDocEncoding or in Unicode.
    % In PDFDocEncoding the em-dash has number 204(oct), thus: \204
    % In unicode the emdash has number 8212(dec) = 2014(hex) = 10000000010100 (bin).
    % Let's prepend zeros until the amount of digits is a multiple of 8:
    %    10000000010100 (bin) = 0010000000010100 (bin).
    % Let's split the binary in two 8-bit=byte registers:
    %    00100000 00010100
    % Take each register for a number:
    %    00100000(bin)=32(dec)=40(oct)
    %    00010100(bin)=20(dec)=24(oct)
    % Let's express each octal number with three digits, i.e., add leading zeros,
    % and with the higher byte prepend \9: \9040\024
    %------------------------------------------------------------------------------

With your specific scenario you can probably do s.th. like this:
\documentclass[english]{book}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[unicode=false]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ForkEntriesByPurpose{%
  \ifx\protect\@unexpandable@protect
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\protect\@ForkEntriesByPurpose
   \protect\@ForkEntriesByPurpose
   \protect\@ForkEntriesByPurpose
  }%
  {\expandafter\texorpdfstring\@gobbletwo}%
}
\@ifdefinable\@ForkEntriesByPurpose{%
  \def\@ForkEntriesByPurpose#1#{%
    \ifx#1\expandafter\@secondoffour\else\expandafter\@firstoffour\fi
  }%
}
\newcommand\@firstoffour[4]{#1}
\newcommand\@secondoffour[4]{#2}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[\ForkEntriesByPurpose{New (Jon)}{New}{New}{New (Jon)}]{New \hfill Jon}
\lipsum[1][1-2]%

\chapter[\ForkEntriesByPurpose{Chapter 2 (Sara)}{Chapter 2}{Chapter 2}{Chapter 2 (Sara)}]{Chapter 2\hfill Sara}
\lipsum[1][1-10]%

\chapter[\ForkEntriesByPurpose{Chapter 3 (Sara)}{Chapter 3}{Chapter 3}{Chapter 3 (Sara)}]{Chapter 3\hfill Sara}
\lipsum[1][1-7]%

\chapter[\ForkEntriesByPurpose{Chapter 4 (Jon)}{Chapter 4}{Chapter 4}{Chapter 4 (Jon)}]{Chapter 4 \hfill Jon}
\lipsum[1][1-4]%

\chapter[\ForkEntriesByPurpose{Chapter 5 (Sara)}{Chapter 5}{Chapter 5}{Chapter 5 (Sara)}]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{%
    \hsize=.5\textwidth
    Chapter 5\\
    There is some awful lengthy thing.
  }%
  \hfill Sara%
}
\lipsum[1][1-10]%

\end{document}



Here is a minimal change solution.  To change the TOC and header you would also need to modify \@chapter.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@
    %\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne% easier not to ask
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \sffamily\bfseries \makebox[2em][r]{\thechapter.} #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[New]{New\hfill Sara}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}


Thanks. It is highly usefull
